# Trying to draw a 'box' using python recursion

Tags: python, recursion, drawing, outline

I am trying to use python recursion in order to draw a box, but have a hard time finding where to start. In principle I want to pass two numbers as arguments which will be the amount of '*''s that are printed both vertically and horizontally like this:

```
>>> drawRectangle(4, 4) 
****
*  *
*  *
****
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must include** a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem and a description of the *specific difficulty* you are having solving it. Stack Overflow is not a homework service to complete your assignment end-to-end. You are expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/) and [An Open Letter to Students with Homework Problems](https://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166) as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever you are requesting a help from community you need to tell what you have tried so far, this way other members don't have to start from scratch.**

```
def box(n, c, k): # n=number of rows, c=number of cols, k=number of rows to keep the track of original number
  if n>0 and c>0:
    if n==1:
      print("*"*c)
    elif n==k:
      print("*"*c)
    else:
      print("*"+" "*(c-2)+"*")
    box(n-1,c, k)

def create_box(n,c):
  box(n,c,n)

create_box(5, 7)

# output
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
```

Answer (score 0):

note: in `python` `function names` are `snake case` and not `camel case` (somthing_somthing and not SomthingSomthing).

for python conventions see [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

---

this function will receive `width` and `height` as parameters and has another parameter `first` with default value `True`.

if `height == 1` it will print a row of `*` and stop

if `first == True` it will print a row of `*` and will call it self again but with `first = False` and `height - 1`

else it will print one `*` and `" " * (width - 2)` and one `*` and will call itself again with `height - 1`

the `first` parameter allows us to print the first row as a full row and the rest up until `height == 1` not as full rows

```
def draw_rectangle(width: int, height: int, first=True):
    if height == 1:
        print("*" * width)
    elif first:
        print("*" * width)
        draw_rectangle(width, height - 1, first=False)
    else:
        print("*" + " " * (width - 2) + "*")
        draw_rectangle(width, height - 1, first=False)


draw_rectangle(4, 4)

# output:
# ****
# *  *
# *  *
# ****
```